# referencing VCAP variables in application.properties

Tags: cloud-foundry

My VCAP looks like below:

```
"VCAP_SERVICES": {
        "rabbitmq": [
                    {
                   "credentials": {
                   "hostname": "10.11.241.52",
                   "ports": {
                             "15672/tcp": "52764",
                             "5672/tcp": "42204"
```

My question is how can I reference the value “52764” in my application.properties? Please be noted that we are building spring boot applications.

Thank you and best regards,
Yashu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that example, you should be able to use properties like these in `application.properties`:

`spring.rabbitmq.host: ${vcap.services.rabbitmq.credentials.hostname}
spring.rabbitmq.port: ${vcap.services.rabbitmq.credentials.ports.15672/tcp}`

The `${vcap.services...}` placeholders are enabled by a Spring Boot environment post-processor. Some details are available in the [JavaDoc for that class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html).

More details can be found in a [Spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry#a-purely-declarative-approach), along with some alternative ways to access the info in `VCAP_SERVICES` in a Spring app.